# pooled resources in Simmer for R - how to use get_server_count correctly

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a simulation model that describes the dispensing process in a hospital pharmacy. I consider 3 main activities, i.e. verifying, dispensing and final checking. How would I be able to define a "pooled resource", i.e. provide for certain activities to be able to resort not only to one, but two types of resources, if needed? In other words, if there are no final checkers available (because they are utilized in the process), how could I allow for pharmacists to do this task, if they are available?

See example of code below. I did not manage to access the number of currently in simulation-time available resources with get_server_count in the trajectory in any way. I usually get error messages along the lines of:

```
Error in UseMethod("get_server_count") : 
  no applicable method for 'get_server_count' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I also tried an if statement in the trajectory to allow for a back-up resource to be used if the primary resource is not available. This got me the same message and an additional one:

```
In if (.) get_server_count("dispenser") > 0 else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

See example code:

```
library(simmer)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

#Defining Simmer environment:
pharmacy <- simmer("Dispensing Process")

#Defining 3 activities, i.e. verifying, dispensing, and final checking, and their
#durations:
dispProcess <- trajectory("dispensing process") %>% 
  seize("pharmacist", 1) %>%
  timeout(5) %>% 
  release("pharmacist", 1) %>%
  log_(get_server_count("dispenser")) %>%
  seize("dispenser", 1) %>%
  timeout(15) %>% 
  release("dispenser", 1) %>%
  seize("final checker", 1) %>%
  timeout(5) %>% 
  release("final checker", 1) 

#Defining number of resources (i.e. staff) available:
pharmacy %>% 
  add_resource("pharmacist", 2) %>% 
  add_resource("dispenser", 4) %>% 
  add_resource("final checker", 2) %>% 
  add_generator("prescription", dispProcess, function() {10}, mon = 2)

#Defining length of simulation run:
pharmacy %>% run(until = 400)

pharmacy %>% get_mon_arrivals() %>% print()
```

With the code above, I would have expected the number of free "dispenser" resources at that point in simulation-time to be shown. This did not happen, as described above.

How can I access this information in the trajectory? Can I use if statement there to make seizing of certain types of resources dependent on their availability?

Exchanging the trajectory code to

```
dispProcess <- trajectory("dispensing process") %>% 
  seize("pharmacist", 1) %>%
  timeout(5) %>% 
  release("pharmacist", 1) %>%
  log_(get_server_count("dispenser")) %>%
  seize("dispenser", 1) %>%
  timeout(15) %>% 
  release("dispenser", 1) %>%
  select(resources = c("pharmacist","final checker"), policy = "shortest-queue") %>%
  seize_selected(amount = 1) %>%
  timeout(5) %>% 
  release_selected(amount = 1)
```

got me the following error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('trajectory', 'R6')"
```

This is strange, as I believe I have used the select command as described in the Advanced Trajectory Usage tutorial (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simmer/vignettes/simmer-03-trajectories.html).

Comment: Changed the trajectory above to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the relevant line:

```
log_(get_server_count("dispenser")) %>%
```

1. See the help page for `get_server_count`. It requires two arguments: 1) the simulation environment and 2) the name of the resource. You provided just the name of the resource.
2. This line executes the function immediately, but you need to provide the name of a function (or an anonymous function) to be executed during the simulation.
3. The output of `get_server_count` is numeric, as is documented, but the `log_` activity requires a string, so you need to convert it.

Putting 1:3 together, the line should read as follows:

```
log_(function() paste(get_server_count(pharmacy, "dispenser"))) %>%
```

About the `if` statement, control statements cannot be used at the activity level. If you need different paths depending on some condition, see the `branch` activity.

Finally, about `select`, both `simmer` and `dplyr` export a `select` function. If you load `dplyr` after `simmer`, `select` refers to the `dplyr` function, and you should call `simmer`'s version as `simmer::select`.

Comment: Thanks for having looked at the code and for your helpful comments, Iñaki. I will try to ensure using the anonymous function more often. Thanks also for having created Simmer.

Comment: I will also watch for commands that are used by several packages. Using simmer::select in the example above and in the code I use for my model (not shown) did the trick!